# Rally Pull Defect Suite from workspace

Tags: rally

i got the code snippet of adding a defect to defect suite from forums.
However, my requirement is to pull defect from defect suite and i am not aware of defect suite information.

***Is there a way to pull collection of defect suites and defects from it.***

Here is the sample code snippet to add defect to defect suite.

```
> import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class addDefectToSuite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@company.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
            String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";      
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129"; 
            String applicationName = "Create defect, add to a defectsuite";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        QueryRequest defectSuiteRequest = new QueryRequest("DefectSuite");
        defectSuiteRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name", "Defects"));
        defectSuiteRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        defectSuiteRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "DS1"));
        QueryResponse defectSuiteQueryResponse = restApi.query(defectSuiteRequest);
        JsonObject defectSuiteJsonObject = defectSuiteQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println("defectSuiteJsonObject" + defectSuiteJsonObject);
        String defectSuiteRef = defectSuiteJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString(); 
        int numberOfDefects = defectSuiteJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Defects").get("Count").getAsInt();
        System.out.println(defectSuiteJsonObject.get("Name") + " ref: " + defectSuiteRef + "number of defects: " + numberOfDefects + " " + defectSuiteJsonObject.get("Defects"));


        try {
            JsonObject defect = new JsonObject();
            defect.addProperty("Name", "bad defect 668");

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("defect", defect);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
            if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                JsonObject defectJsonObject = createResponse.getObject();
                String defectRef = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", defectRef));  
                JsonObject defectSuitesOfThisDefect = (JsonObject) defectJsonObject.get("DefectSuites");
                int numberOfSuites = defectSuitesOfThisDefect.get("Count").getAsInt();
                System.out.println("number of defect suites this defect is part of: " + numberOfSuites);
                QueryRequest defectSuitesOfThisDefectRequest = new QueryRequest(defectSuitesOfThisDefect);
                JsonArray suites = restApi.query(defectSuitesOfThisDefectRequest).getResults();
                System.out.println("suites: " + suites);
                suites.add(defectSuiteJsonObject);
                System.out.println("suites after add: " + suites);
                //Update defect: add to defectsutites collection
                JsonObject defectUpdate = new JsonObject();
                defectUpdate.add("DefectSuites", suites);
                UpdateRequest updateDefectRequest = new UpdateRequest(defectRef,defectUpdate);
                UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateDefectRequest);
                if (updateResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully updated defect: " + defectJsonObject.get("FormattedID"));
                }
                else {
                    String[] updateErrors;
                    updateErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    for (int i=0; i<updateErrors.length;i++) {
                        System.out.println(updateErrors[i]);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   

    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what it is you are trying to do.  The code above works, but there is definitely a shorter way to do it via the collection modification endpoints.  Do you need to create defects under a specific defect suite?  Or do you just want to load the defects collection under an existing defect suite?

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for response, I just want to load the defects collection under an existing defect suite

Answer (score 0):

The Defect object has a DefectSuites collection, so you could just query for all defects where DefectSuites contains your specified DefectSuite:

```
QueryRequest defectsRequest = new QueryRequest("Defect");
defectsRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
defectsRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("DefectSuites", "contains", defectSuiteRef));
QueryResponse defectsResponse = restApi.query(defectsRequest);
```

Or, you can come at it from the other way by querying the Defects collection directly on your DefectSuite in your original code above:

```
JsonObject defectsCollection = defectSuiteJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Defects");
QueryRequest defectsRequest = new QueryRequest(defectsCollection);
defectSuiteRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name")); 
QueryResponse defectsResponse = restApi.query(defectsRequest);
```